# C# late evaluation cause unexpected result on Dictionary.Add()

Tags: c#, dictionary, lazy-loading

i have this code, TheData is a collection with 3 items:

```
ICollection<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (CData data in TheData) 
{
   Thread t = new Thread(DoSomething);
   threads.Add(t);
   t.Start(data);
}

foreach (var thread in threads)
   thread.Join();
```

The DoSomething method:

```
static void OpenConnections(CData deviceData)
{

   CDevice deviceInstance = new CDevice((EDeviceType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EDeviceType), deviceData.Type));
   m_deviceManager.AddDevice(deviceInstance);

   // More stuff...
}
```

so far so good.

the `m_deviceManager.AddDevice`, adds the new item to an inner dictionary.

In most execution, after the Join line, the `m_deviceManager` dictionary has all 3 values as expected.

The problem is that in some of the executions, after the Join line, the `m_deviceManager` dictionary has 3 values, but some of them are null...

`TheData` is exactly the same each time (read from a file).
When adding break points, this never happens.
My suspection is some kind of late evaluation.
any ideas for why this happens? and to prevent it?

Comment: Do you have multiple threads adding to the same dictionary? It sounds like it - and that's broken to start with. `Dictionary<,>` is not thread-safe. Consider using `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` instead.

Comment: Also, ditch Threads and go with Tasks.  Easier to work with, used in async/await.

Comment: Thanks Jon, If the add to the dictionary fails because of the multi threading, shouldn't I get an exception? The thing is, the dictionary always contains 3 elements, just the value is null.

Comment: @JonSkeet excellent answer!  I had no idea there was such a thing!

Comment: BTW - how do you upvote a comment??

Comment: move the mouse over the comment, a little arrow will apear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary isn't thread safe, so you have to synchronise the access to it so that only one thread at a time can use it.

Common practive is to create an object specifically to use as identifier for locks. This should have the same life span as the data that you protect, so if `m_deviceMananger` is static, it should be too:

```
private static object m_sync = new Object();
```

Now you can lock around the code that accesses the dictionary:

```
static void OpenConnections(CData deviceData) {

   CDevice deviceInstance = new CDevice((EDeviceType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EDeviceType), deviceData.Type));
   lock (m_sync) {
      m_deviceManager.AddDevice(deviceInstance);
   }

   // More stuff...
}
```